# Rodar mais de um arquivo csv utilizando python

Tags: python, csv

Estou com a seguinte dúvida: Eu leio um arquivo csv e neste arquivo eu quero tirar as linhas 0:9 e deixar da 10 em diante. Eu fiz esse código e parece estar tudo ok. Meu problema é: Como ler vários arquivos csv's iguais a esse e fazer esse mesmo processo.

```
import csv

with open("teste2.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = [r for r in reader]
    header = data[0:9]
    data = data[10:]
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

[image: Arquivo csv]

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira de fazer é usando as funções `listdir` e `isfile`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile

diretorio = '/home/usuario'
lista = listdir(diretorio)
for f in lista:
    if isfile(f):
        print(f)
```

Com este script você pode adaptar a sua necessidade, ao invês de imprimir você pode pode executar a rotina que deseja.